# Installed compass with gem but still getting error not found in "grunt serve"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gruntjs, rubygems, compass

I installed compass using `sudo gem install compass` but when I run `grunt serve` I get the error:

```
Warning: not found: compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any idea why this isn't working? How do I get compass installed properly?

I'm on openSUSE LEAP (KDE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to install RubyGem-Compass from RPM directly:

http://software.opensuse.org/package/ruby2.1-rubygem-compass

```
sudo zypper install ruby2.1-rubygem-compass-1.0.1-10.1.x86_64.rpm
```